# Using mysql with rails - how do I set this up?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use mysql with a rails app (I have never used mysql before). My experience has been solely with sqlite3 and postgresql, which are really easy to use.

I am now creating a new app to learn to use mysql. I installed mysql with homebrew (brew install mysql), and created a new rails app that uses mysql rather than sqlite3. I have included the right gem in my gemfile (gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.6').

However, I don't know how to proceed. I have not set up anything more in mysql other than to install it on my system, I don't understand anything to do with how you set it up to run, where it stores the database for my app, and so on.

Please could anyone let me know either the next steps, or a tutorial that would get me understanding enough to develop my app to function just as it would with a simpler (sqlite) database system?

Comment: What OS are you installing it on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the next step would be **create the database** in "your system" and let **Rails** know that you want to use that database.

If you want to create the database using the MySQL server directly, you want to log in by using this command from your console:

```
mysql -u root
```

By default, mysql root user doesn't need a password, otherwise you would specify it with -p, so it would be:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Once you are logged in your MySQL server, you want to create the database by doing this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_project_database;
```

You might want to look deeper into users and permissions in MySQL, but this is just a starting point :).

If you want to avoid going into the MySQL server and do it the Rails way, you can create the database using rake.  You want to use this command: `rake db:create`. This will do the same that we did before, but notice that before doing that command you need to create the **database.yml** file. So let's do that:

You want to have a **database.yml** file like this:

```
development:
    host: localhost
    adapter: mysql2
    database: my_project_database
    username: root (notice that you might want to change this user later)
    password:
```

I suppose that next step would be to create the [Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) that would generate the tables you want to use and so on.

One of the things that I love the most about Rails is its [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) called [Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). It will abstract all database operations, so you don't have to worry either if you are calling a MySQL or a SQLite...

Comment: I don't understand where I would do this.. Could you be more specific? Once I have a db up a running, I understand how to make migrations and so on. I just can't get to that point

Comment: I have edited my question. Basically you want to log into your MySQL server and create the database. BUT, there is a Rails way of doing that without having to type any MySQL related commands :P- See my edit

Comment: AHh that is more clear. Thanks for the help.. I think my installation may have screwed up, I get this error on both mysql -u and rake db:create : Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' Any input? THanks again

Comment: I think I'm supposed to run a mysql server? I just did brew install mysql, is there some sort of other thing to install to run this?

Comment: I have never used brew...But yes, you need a mysql server up and running. I believe you might want to either look for other questions related to this issue, or create your own question specifying your problem, OS you are running, etc...Check this out though: http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/

Comment: here, i learned I just needed to start mysqld (in Terminal => $ mysqld) if you add this to your answer it will be more specific, for other readers. thanks again!